# How do I add a button in a Tkinter window using Python 3?

Tags: python, button, input, tkinter

I was using python and experimenting with tkinter windows. I want to add a button to my window.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at any tkinter tutorial? Just about any of them covers this.

Comment: Thank you I will look for one

Comment: Read the documentation and follow the examples?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place to ask questions that have answers in hundreds of other places. You're expected to do some research before asking. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PythonSpot](https://pythonspot.com/en/tk-window-and-button/):

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
    print "click!"

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```